# How the callFunctionCall will work using the FunctionCall structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "C:/MediaFiles/File/STUDY/P1/Structure Function Pointer/Manager.h"

void callFunctionCall_addFun(int a,int b);

void callFunctionCall_subsFun(int a,int b);

void callFunctionCall_divideFun(int a,int b);

void callFunctionCall_modeFun(int a,int b);

FunctionCall* FunctionCall_GetInterface(void);

FunctionCall callFunctionCall = 
{
    callFunctionCall_addFun,
    callFunctionCall_subsFun,
    callFunctionCall_divideFun,
    callFunctionCall_modeFun
};


FunctionCall* FunctionCall_GetInterface(void)
{
    printf("FunctionCall_GetInterface --> Called\n");
    return &callFunctionCall;
}

void callFunctionCall_addFun(int a,int b)
{
    printf("callFunctionCall_addFun --> Called\n");
    printf("Add of %d and %d is: %d\n",a,b,(a+b));
}

void callFunctionCall_subsFun(int a,int b)
{
    printf("callFunctionCall_subsFun --> Called\n");
    printf("Subtract of %d and %d is: %d\n",a,b,(a-b));
}

void callFunctionCall_divideFun(int a,int b)
{
    printf("callFunctionCall_divideFun --> Called\n");
    printf("Divide of %d and %d is: %d\n",a,b,(a/b));
}

void callFunctionCall_modeFun(int a,int b)
{
    printf("callFunctionCall_modeFun --> Called\n");
    printf("Mode of %d and %d is: %d\n",a,b,(a%b));
}

int main(void)
{
    FunctionCall *mainCall= FunctionCall_GetInterface();
    printf("%x\n",*mainCall);
    return 0;
}
```

and Manager.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct FunctionCall{
    void (*addFun)(int a,int b);
    void (*subsFun)(int a,int b);
    void (*divideFun)(int a,int b);
    void (*modeFun)(int a,int b);
} FunctionCall;
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. What are you asking?

Comment: I literally have no idea what are you asking for...

Comment: More information would be helpful. 
One common practice is to clarify expected behavior and actual behavior. SO other can help you fill up the gap if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct FunctionCall` can be initialised with four suitable function pointers, as your code does in a global variable:

```
FunctionCall callFunctionCall = 
{
    callFunctionCall_addFun,
    callFunctionCall_subsFun,
    callFunctionCall_divideFun,
    callFunctionCall_modeFun
};
```

Armed with your functions in `main` you can call any of them:

```
mainCall->divideFun(10, 1);
```

giving

```
Divide of 10 and 1 is: 10
```

This will allow you to swap out what happens for each of the four function pointers in the struct.

Comment: Here, we can call divideFun(10,1) directly then why using mainCall->divideFun(10,1) ?

Comment: Well, now you can swap it with other functions, e.g. log what happened when as well as divide. Change the language in the message from English to something else. You have options, like a kind of polymorphism.